# Issue passing UTF-8 encoded data to data extension through SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, encoding

I have a problem with the data displayed in one field and got specific characters : "Espace Commercial RenÃ© Coty" rather than "Espace Commercial René Coty"

I tried the formulee

```
CAST(CONVERT(OPP_MAG.Rue__c USING UTF8) as binary) as OPP_MAG_Rue,
```

in the SQL but I have the error: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near 'USING'.

```
Select
opportunity.Id                                as OPP_Id,
opportunity.Name                              as OPP_Name,
opportunity.StageName                         as OPP_Stage,
opportunity.Loss_Reason__c                    as OPP_RaisonDeLaPerte,
opportunity.LeadSource                        as OPP_LeadSource,
opportunity.Pr_cision_source__c               as OPP_PrecisionSource,
opportunity.Amount                            as OPP_Amount,
opportunity.IsWon                             as OPP_IsWon,
opportunity.MYOPLA__c                         as OPP_Myopla,
opportunity.MarqueGroupe__c                   as OPP_MarqueGroupe,
opportunity.CreatedDate                       as OPP_CreatedDate,
opportunity.CloseDate                         as OPP_CloseDate,
opportunity.LastModifiedDate                  as OPP_LastModifiedDate,
opportunity.Cat_gorie_Produits__c             as OPP_CategorieProduit,
account.FirstName                             as ACC_FirstName,
account.LastName                              as ACC_LastName,
account.IsPersonAccount                       as ACC_IsPersonAccount,
account.ShippingCity                          as ACC_ShippingCity,
account.ShippingCountry                       as ACC_ShippingCountry,
account.ShippingStreet                        as ACC_ShippingStreet,
account.ShippingPostalCode                    as ACC_ShippingPostalCode,
account.PersonEmail                           as ACC_Email,
account.PersonMobilePhone                     as ACC_Mobile,
account.et4ae5__Mobile_Country_Code__pc       as ACC_MobileCountryCode,
account.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail              as ACC_DesabonnementEmail,
account.et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__pc       as ACC_DesabonnementMobile,
account.CreatedDate                           as ACC_CreatedDate,
account.Account_Source__pc                    as ACC_AccountSource,
account.Precision_source__c                   as ACC_PrecisionSource,
account.Marque_groupe__c                      as ACC_MarqueGroupe,
account.NbDeCommandesPassees__c               as ACC_NbCommandesPassees,
account.TECH_PanierMoyen__c                   as ACC_PanierMoyen,
account.TECH_DateDerniereCommande__c          as ACC_DateDerniereCommande,
account.TECH_MontantDeLaDerniereCommande__c   as ACC_MontantDerniereCommande,
account.TECH_NbCases__pc                      as ACC_NbTickets,
account.TECH_NbDeTicketsOuverts__c            as ACC_NbTicketsOuverts,
account.TECH_DateDuDernierTicketCree__c       as ACC_DateDernierTicketOuvert,
account.PersonContactId                       as ACC_SubscriberKey,
magasin.Name                                  as Magasin_Name,
magasin.Code_Magasin__c                       as Magasin_Code,
magasin.Region__c                             as Magasin_Region,
magasin.TelephoneMagasin__c                   as Magasin_Tel,
magasin.Rue__c                                as Magasin_Rue,
magasin.Code_Postal__c                        as Magasin_CodePostal,
magasin.Ville__c                              as Magasin_Ville,
RM.Name                                       as ACC_MAG_RM_Nom,
RM.Email                                      as ACC_MAG_RM_Email,
RM.MobilePhone                                as ACC_MAG_RM_Phone,
Anim.Name                                     as ACC_MAG_ANIM_Nom,
Anim.Email                                    as ACC_MAG_ANIM_Email,
Anim.MobilePhone                              as ACC_MAG_ANIM_Phone,
OPP_MAG.Name                                  as OPP_MAG_Nom,
OPP_MAG.Code_Magasin__c                       as OPP_MAG_Code,
OPP_MAG.Region__c                             as OPP_MAG_Region,
OPP_MAG.TelephoneMagasin__c                   as OPP_MAG_Tel,
CAST(CONVERT(OPP_MAG.Rue__c USING UTF8) as binary) as OPP_MAG_Rue,
OPP_MAG.Code_Postal__c                        as OPP_MAG_CodePostal,
OPP_MAG.Ville__c                              as OPP_MAG_Ville,
OPP_MAG_RM.Name                               as OPP_MAG_RM_Nom,
OPP_MAG_RM.Email                              as OPP_MAG_RM_Email,
OPP_MAG_RM.MobilePhone                        as OPP_MAG_RM_Phone,
OPP_MAG_ANIM.Name                             as OPP_MAG_ANIM_Nom,
OPP_MAG_ANIM.Email                            as OPP_MAG_ANIM_Email,
OPP_MAG_ANIM.MobilePhone                      as OPP_MAG_ANIM_Phone,
OPP_OWNER.Name                                as OPP_OWNER_Nom,
OPP_OWNER.Email                               as OPP_OWNER_Email,
OPP_OWNER.MobilePhone                         as OPP_OWNER_Phone,
OPP_OWNER.TECH_ProfilName__c                  as OPP_OWNER_Profil,
OPP_CREA.Name                                 as OPP_CREA_Nom,
OPP_CREA.Email                                as OPP_CREA_Email,
OPP_CREA.MobilePhone                          as OPP_CREA_Phone,
OPP_CREA.TECH_ProfilName__c                   as OPP_CREA_Profil,
opportunity.Opportunity_Child__c              as OPPCHILD_Name,
oppchild.StageName                            as OPPCHILD_Stage,
oppchild.Loss_Reason__c                       as OPPCHILD_RaisonDeLaPerte,
oppchild.Amount                               as OPPCHILD_Amount,
oppchild.LeadSource                           as OPPCHILD_LeadSource,
oppchild.Pr_cision_source__c                  as OPPCHILD_PrecisionSource,
oppchild.IsWon                                as OPPCHILD_IsWon,
oppchild.MYOPLA__c                            as OPPCHILD_Myopla,
oppchild.MarqueGroupe__c                      as OPPCHILD_MarqueGroupe,
oppchild.CreatedDate                          as OPPCHILD_CreatedDate,
oppchild.CloseDate                            as OPPCHILD_CloseDate,
oppchild.LastModifiedDate                     as OPPCHILD_LastModifiedDate,
oppchild.Cat_gorie_Produits__c                as OPPCHILD_CategorieProduit,
OPPPROD.UnitPrice                             as OPPPROD_UnitPrice,
OPPPROD.Quantity                              as OPPPROD_Quantity,
OPPPROD.Prix_Total_TTC__c                     as OPPPROD_PrixTotalTTC,
OPPPROD.Id                                    as OPPPROD_Id,
PROD.Name                                     as PROD_Name,
PROD.Marche__c                                as PROD_Marche,
PROD.Type_de_produit__c                       as PROD_TypeProduit,
PROD.Marque_groupe__c                         as PROD_MarqueGroupe,
PROD.CFP_Categorie__c                         as PROD_CategorieCFP,
PROD.CFP_Sous_categorie__c                    as PROD_SousCategorieCFP,
PROD.ProductCode                              as PROD_ProductCode


/* récupère toutes les lignes de produit mais aussi toutes les opp qui en ont pas*/
FROM OpportunityLineItem_Salesforce OPPPROD
RIGHT JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce opportunity
ON OPPPROD.OpportunityId = opportunity.Id

/* détails produits */
LEFT JOIN Product2_Salesforce PROD
ON OPPPROD.Product2Id = PROD.Id

INNER JOIN Account_Salesforce account
ON opportunity.AccountId = account.Id

/* Magasin de référence sur la fiche du client*/
LEFT JOIN Magasin__c_Salesforce magasin 
ON account.Magasin_de_R_f_rence__c = magasin.id

/* RM = propriétaire sur le magasin de ref*/
/* note= on ne peut pas utliser le mot 'user' techniquement déjà pris */
LEFT JOIN User_Salesforce RM
ON magasin.OwnerId = RM.Id

/* Anim = Anim sur le magasin de ref */
/* note = on ne peut pas utliser le mot 'user' techniquement déjà pris */
LEFT JOIN User_Salesforce Anim
ON magasin.Animateur__c = Anim.Id

/* MAGASIN DE L'OPP */
LEFT JOIN Magasin__c_Salesforce OPP_MAG
ON opportunity.Magasin__c = OPP_MAG.Id

/*RM DU MAGASIN DE L'OPP */
LEFT JOIN User_Salesforce OPP_MAG_RM
ON OPP_MAG.OwnerId = OPP_MAG_RM.Id

/*ANIM DU MAGASIN DE L'OPP */
LEFT JOIN User_Salesforce OPP_MAG_ANIM
ON OPP_MAG.Animateur__c = OPP_MAG_ANIM.Id

/*OWNER DE L'OPP */
LEFT JOIN User_Salesforce OPP_OWNER
ON opportunity.OwnerId = OPP_OWNER.Id

/*CREATEUR DE L'OPP */
LEFT JOIN User_Salesforce OPP_CREA
ON opportunity.CreatedById = OPP_CREA.Id

/*INFOS DE L'OPP ENFANT */
LEFT JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce oppchild
ON opportunity.Opportunity_Child__c = oppchild.Id

WHERE account.PersonEmail IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: the brackets in `CAST[CONVERT(OPP_MAG.Rue__c USING UTF8] as binary) as ...` are disjointed. Try first to replacing the [ ] with round brackets, so that the inner function `Convert( )` and the outer function `CAST( )` are opened and closed correctly.

Comment: Hello @JonasLamberty, thanks for the reply. I updadted the SQL and now I have a new type of error : An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near 'USING'. Do you have any idea?